# <picture> is not scaling with viewport size

Tags: html, css

I apologize if this is riddled with errors, but I am very new to HTML and in need of some help with getting my images to scale with the viewport size. The img will scale until a certain point, then it begins to overlap the container, along with the alternate images I've included using . If anyone has any feedback it would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my CodePen WIP:

https://codepen.io/m34629/pen/GRwjJBm

I've tried implementing max-width: 100% which hasn't worked.

The following allows the img to scale with the viewport to a certain point, but does not scale beyond that.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Edit: My styling for my navigation bar also disappears when the viewport is made smaller. Although this is a secondary issue, if anyone has any advice as to fixing this it would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Please post your [mcve] here, not on codepen, jsfiddle, or another third party site. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing closing brackets `}` for the media queries you have set up. Always make sure to close all rules, including the @media at-rules.

CSS creates nested @media rules in this situation (by "error/mistake", guessing where to close rules). That's why you're experiencing unexpected results. Your img rule is within these nested media queries, and in this case it basically means that the rule is active for screen widths greater than 1008px.

Take a look at the browser developer tools and you will see what the browser interprets:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem. I hadn't realized there needed to be a second bracket at the bottom.